# Could someone help me configure MinGW in SublimeText 3? (Newbie)

Tags: gcc, build, sublimetext3, gnu

I downloaded MinGW following the first link here https://isocpp.org/get-started and now I need to configure it in SubimeText 3. I know I should go to Tools > Build System > New Build System... But what should I specify there?

I use Win7x64. And MinGW is in C:\MinGW

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The complete reference for build systems is [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html). The first thing you need to do is make sure that the `C:\MinGW\bin` directory is in your `PATH`, then restart Sublime so the change gets picked up.

Once you've done that, create a new build system with the following contents:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["gcc", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
    "shell": true,

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe"],
            "shell": true
        }
    ]
}
```

and save it as `Packages/User/C.sublime-build` where the `Packages` folder is the one opened by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**.

You can now choose this build system by selecting **`Tools -> Build System -> C`**. Once you are ready to compile, save your source file, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to build. To run the program, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and a `cmd` window will open up to run the resulting `.exe` file, then stay open until you close it (so you can see any output produced by the program).

You can try to use the `C++` build system that comes with Sublime, but some users have run into issues with it in the past, especially on Windows, so this custom one may suit your needs better.

Good luck!