# Sublime Text 3 does not accept fortran from MinGW

Tags: fortran, windows-10, mingw, sublimetext3

I am trying to set fortran (G95) from MinGW to work in Sublime Text 3.
I looked at [How do you configure MinGW with Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742296/how-do-you-configure-mingw-with-sublime-text-3) and [Could someone help me configure MinGW in SublimeText 3? (Newbie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503596/could-someone-help-me-configure-mingw-in-sublimetext-3-newbie) a I found this:

```
{
"cmd": ["gcc", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",
"shell": true,

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe"],
        "shell": true
    }
]
}
```

so i created the file packages/user/fortran(G95).sublime-build. There I dont know what to write in ${file_path} or ${file_base_name} variable so I tried this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["gcc", "C:/MinGW/bin", "-o", "g95.exe"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "C:/MinGW/bin",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
    "shell": true,

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "C:/MinGW/bin/g95.exe"],
            "shell": true
        }
    ]
}
```

but it returns:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot find C:/MinGW/bin: Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status [Finished in 0.3s].

Was I doing it right or did I mess up something doring the creation of the file.

Thank you very much for any advice and help to make this work.

PS:I already have in PATH C:/MinGW/bin and C:/MinGW/mingw32/bin. And I use Windows 10 64-bit.

Edit: 
Now I did change the file back to this:

```
{
"cmd": ["gcc", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",
"shell": true,

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe"],
        "shell": true
    }
]
}
```

But it says that it does not know the write function and more in my Hello world program.

> C:\Users\TPN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccV3Loja.o:helloworld.f90:(.text+0x3b):
>   undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
>   C:\Users\TPN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccV3Loja.o:helloworld.f90:(.text+0x59):
>   undefined reference to`_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
>   C:\Users\TPN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccV3Loja.o:helloworld.f90:(.text+0x67):
>   undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
>   C:\Users\TPN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccV3Loja.o:helloworld.f90:(.text+0x8a):
>   undefined reference to`_gfortran_set_args'
>   C:\Users\TPN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccV3Loja.o:helloworld.f90:(.text+0x9e):
>   undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_options' collect2.exe: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status [Finished in 1.0s]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not change `${file}`, `${file_base_name}` or `${working_dir}`. Theses variables are parsed by ST to execute the right cmd, see the [official help](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build) and the more complete [unoffical help](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html).

As you already added `C:/MinGW/bin` and `C:/MinGW/mingw32/bin` to your `PATH`, just revert to the original file `packages/user/fortran(G95).sublime-build`, with the following changes to handle fortran files then restart Sublime-text and you should be good to go.

```
{
"cmd": ["gfortran", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.f, source.f90, source.f95",
"shell": true,
"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe"],
        "shell": true
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Have you changed the gcc (C compiler) for gfortran (Fortran compiler)?

Comment: Thank you very much for help, but now it gives this message:

gfortran: error: 'C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Ahoj.f90': Invalid argument

When I write this code:
program H
 write(*,*) "Hello"
end program H

Comment: This is another problem. Open a new question.